# Aptana eclipse plugin offline installation

Tags: aptana

I have a specific set of pc that cannot be wired to intenet. 
How i can install aptana eclipse plugin on them? 
Thanks a lot
Francesco

Answer (score 2):

just go to the following link and download the plugin and give the path of installed plugin in eclipse->Help>Install New Software->work with textfield

http://d1iwq2e2xrohf.cloudfront.net/tools/studio/plugin/install/studio3/3.0.8.201201201626/com.aptana.feature.studio-3.0.8.201201201626-7E37L7HFGQGNJXIW3R_Iz0JjtqJe.zip

Comment: Very nice advice, but I got the error: 'Missing requirement: Aptana CSS Editor 3.0.3.1326757715 (com.aptana.editor.css 3.0.3.1326757715) requires 'bundle org.mortbay.jetty.util 0.0.0' but it could not be found'